# Python & Sqlite3 - Subset one table then join on two other tables

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python and sqlite3. I have 3 tables:

Table 1:
Col A

Table 2: 
Col A | Col B

Table 3: 
Col B

I want the first 500k rows from  Table 1 and any matching rows from Table 2 that have matching rows from Table 3. How do I do this? I was thinking something like this

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')

      conn.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1 LIMIT 500000 AS sample
      LEFT JOIN Table2
      ON sample.A = Table2.A
      LEFT JOIN Table3 ON table2.B = Table3.B')
```

But I get this error: `OperationalError: near "AS": syntax error`

The result should be 500k rows with all columns found in all 3 Tables.
 Apologies if any of my wording is difficult to understand.

Comment: You are right do that first and see the result. In my opinion too the left join must work. But make sure you c]\have common filed or attribute to compare with and make joins.

Comment: And what is your error or undesired result with your attempt?

Comment: This is what I get: OperationalError: near "AS": syntax error

Comment: `LIMIT` has to be at the end. Or you have to create subquery inside `( )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @furas said, `LIMIT` has to be at the end of the complete statement.

What you actually want to do is most likely a subquery, like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 LIMIT 500000) AS sample
  LEFT JOIN Table2
  ON sample.A = Table2.A
  LEFT JOIN Table3 ON table2.B = Table3.B
```